# Using regex to get data from a binary stream via the command line

Tags: regex, command-line, grep

I have a hacky thing that I'd like to do via the command line because I'd rather not write a program to do it.  For some background, the sensor is just sending UDP packets that are simply caught with netcat, `nc -ul 192.168.1.1 10000 > output.dat`.  In this stream, there's occasionally an error.  I have a binary data stream from a sensor that will occasionally send an error message as "$ERROR<binary for 129 bytes>".

I would like to come up with some way to parse this error message so that I can just pipe the matches to a file.  I believe that the proper regex would be `(\$ERROR).{129}`, but I've had no luck actually implementing it.  I've been simulating the data stream by doing `cat file.bin | grep -aEi '(\$ERROR).{129}'` but it's not working as I'm getting more characters than the error message.

I'm hoping to use this to watch a stream for the error message and redirect it to a file.  Any suggestions on how to fix this regex would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output? Also, add a tag for the regex engine, which I assume would be the grep tag. The excerpt for regex says "..all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is fundamentally a line-oriented tool. If the 129 bytes could contain null bytes or what have you, all bets are off; but maybe try

```
grep -zEo '$ERROR.{129}' file.bin
```

where the `-z` option is non-standard, and says to use null bytes instead of newlines as the delimiter between "lines"; and the `-o` option says to print only the match, not the entire "line" where the match was found.

The parentheses around `$ERROR` didn't contribute anything useful, so I took them out.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` just filters the line where `$ERROR` can be found. If you want to do some processing on it, you need to go a step further, like using `cut`, like in this example:

```
cat file.txt | cut -c 1-10
```

This only shows the first ten characters of each line of the file.

So, your solution could be:

```
cat file.bin | grep -aEi '(\$ERROR).{129}' | cut -c 1-10
```

Obviously, as you file contains binary characters, you might need to use `cut -b`, for cutting the bytes:

```
cat file.bin | grep -aEi '(\$ERROR).{129}' | cut -b 1-10
```

**Edit**: as commented by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee), this can be improved to:

```
grep -aEi '(\$ERROR).{129}' file.bin | cut -b 1-10
```

Comment: You'll want to get rid of the [useless `cat`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) here.

Comment: @tripleee: you're right, I've adapted my answer accordingly.